# MySQL get Top 5 and then order them by another column

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Since I'm new to MySQL I'll need some advice. I want to query the Top 5 of one column and sort them afterwards by another column in MySQL.

I can get the Top 5 via...

```
SELECT column1,column2
FROM table 
ORDER BY column1 DESC
LIMIT 5
```

... but how can I now order this result by column2? Any ideas?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get your top results then do another sub select and reorder your results

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    column1,
    column2 
  FROM
    TABLE 
  ORDER BY column1 DESC 
  LIMIT 5) t 
ORDER BY column2
```